# Move values from one column to other in Oracle table

Tags: oracle10g

I have around 100,000 records in my Oracle table.

```
TableMaster
-----------
TabID
Column1
Column2
```

How do I update all the records so that Column1 values are moved to Column2, and Column2 values are moved to column1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```
UPDATE TableMaster SET Column1 = Column2, Column2 = Column1
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify the table, changing the column names.

Comment: +1, however this will also swap any constraints on the columns, for good or ill